# Using array formula in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

Trying to make an `ARRAYFORMULA` that executes a query function which takes a reference to the current position of the row number and the specified column name.
This is my version of formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(DB!A:H,"select G where A="&address(TEXT(ROW(C:C),"B0")),1))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: to create a formula that applies to the whole column and it take row address of the current row

Comment: You'll have to be more specific in your post. State what you want to achieve, what you've done, and what issues you have.

Comment: hi i am trying to write a formula which can take up the reference of the current row/ cell address and perform a query and return the output. I want to apply this formula to the whole column

Answer (score 0):

Functions that return an array like QUERY can't be "used" on an ARRAYFORMULA as it already returns an array of values.

Comment: what can be done to apply a formula to the while column. the condition being as the cell value changes going down the column the formula should take up the row/cell address and apply the formula.